# Interactive Brokers Java API '200 | No security definition has been found for the request' while placing a futures order

Tags: java, api, interactive, broker

I'm trying to place an order using the Interactive Brokers Java API but I'm getting an the '200 | No security definition has been found for the request' error and I don't know what's happening and the API documentation doesn't help too much. Here's a pice of code for the contract and order

```
    contract.m_localSymbol = "ESF13"; // "ESJ13-FUT-GLOBEX";
    contract.m_secIdType = "ISIN"; // International Securities Identification Number
    contract.m_secId = "US0378331005"; // APPLE
    contract.m_secType = "ISIN";
    order.m_action = "BUY";
    order.m_totalQuantity = 1;
    order.m_orderType = "MKT";
```

I need some help to understand what's going on here

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing to different securities in your contract specification, m_localSymbol refers to a ES future while the m_secId refers to AAPL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to trade the ES future? That is the way you should do it:

```
contract.m_symbol = "ES";
contract.m_exchange ="GLOBEX";
contract.m_secType = "fut";
contract.m_expiry = "20160916"; // write your expiration there
contract.m_currency = "USD";
```